# Design Tool for Xamarin Forms PCL XAML?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

With VS2017, is there a design tool available to design traditional XAML pages in a Xamarin Forms PCL? E.G. forms with a XAML header starting with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
```

Answer (score 1):

For Xamarin.Forms XAML you have to write your design layout manually. There is no drag and drop kind of thing supported yet.

While writing your design code in XAML, however, you can see the changes reflected on with [XAML Previewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer?tabs=vswin).

If XAML Previewer is not enabled in your Visual Studio then you can use the View > Other Windows > Xamarin.Forms Previewer menu in Visual Studio to open the preview window

You can, however, use tools like

[LiveXAML](http://livexaml.com)

[Xamarin Live Player](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/)

[Xamarin Live Reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/live-reload)

These shows changes in your XAML without recompilation.